# openSUSE - can't ping to internet

Tags: networking, opensuse

I have a fresh openSUSE server. I can ping it from the LAN and the server can ping the client. But the server is unable to ping any website from the internet?

I already entered the correct gateway and dns-nameserver to the file `/etc/resolv.conf` and restart the network by executing `rcnetwork restart`.
I even entered 8.8.8.8 (google) as nameserver.

But I can't ping www.google.de or any other site.

What should I check?

**Traceroute**

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.40.20  0.337 ms  0.291 ms  0.267 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
```

**Netstat:**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.40.20   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.40.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: Run `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8` and note the point at which the responses stop appearing. Is that point on one of your networks or your ISP?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, no

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, good hint. I added the traceroute. It looks like it stops at the gateway? Maybe it is not allowed in the firewall of the gateway?

Comment: Add "netstat -rn" output to your question.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I added the output. I had to install netstat first with `zypper install net-tools-deprecated`.

Comment: Suse must have changed a lot for it to consider netstat as a typo.  But you may need to install a network tools package.

Comment: you can reach the gateway, and google name server answers pings, so you should inspect the gateway.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, Where do you see that google nameserver answers pings? If I ping google then I get 100% packet loss.

Comment: I tested it myself. So, if you don't get replies, it's your problem ;-)

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, How is it going to help me if it works on your system?

Comment: I find it easier to solve a problem when I know where it originates.

Comment: Any other system using the same gateway?

Comment: Yes, my windows client. I have access to the internet on it.

Comment: For newer openSUSE installations `netconfig -f update` seems to have helped lots of times.

Comment: @eblock, that worked!! Please write an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @eblock, oh wait, im unsure if my network admin solved it or the command. He just wrote an email a minute after I executed the command.

Comment: No problem, I'll delete the answer if it's not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

There have been many reports in the openSUSE [forums](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/497586-hostname-resolution-stopped-working!?s=2edc12a945fceb2f6a5f74d1fe735d34&highlight=netconfig%20update) about problems similar or exactly like this. 
In most cases running a `sudo /sbin/netconfig -f update` helped in many cases.