# Can't ping a SUSE server from an OpenSUSE server

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse

I am new to Linux OS. I have two Linux servers but one is running OpenSUSE flavour and another is running SUSE. Both of them are able to ping the same flavours but not each other.

Actually I was trying to use `scp` or `sshpass` across the flavours and it wasn't working so I tried using ping it wasn't working either.

- from OpenSUSE server : `ping <SUSE_SERVER_IP>`
- from SUSE server : `ping <OpenSUSE_SERVER_IP>`

and the same goes with `scp` command.

These commands just hang and do nothing until `ctrl+c` is pressed. What am I doing wrong here?

Additional Info : I can ping internet from SUSE but not from OpenSUSE

**Update : 
OpenSUSE server network config :**

[image]

default gateway :

[image]

Netstat :

[image]

**SUSE server network config :**

[image]

default gateway :

[image]

Netstat :

[image]

Comment: Include the network config of both systems in your question. IP, subnet mask, gateway, routes

Comment: @Panki Sorry but would it be safe to post info from `ifconfig` here? I am new to networking so i am little concerned.

Comment: You mentioned https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/476281/117549 in chat; can you update your post with the results of that answer (`sudo /sbin/netconfig -f update`)?

Comment: @Panki I have added the network config. Please tell me if you need anything else.

Comment: @JeffSchaller `sudo /sbin/netconfig -f update` executes but it doesn't solve the problem. I can't ping anything on the internet with OpenSUSE.

Comment: These two machines are on different subnets. How are they connected?